# magento - webserver question

Tags: html, url, web

I've uploaded the Magento installation file to my hosting and I've been told to go to the URL you uploaded it to using you browser, then the installation wizard will run you through the processes.

I uploaded to `/home/domain/public_html/magneto`

What URL should I use to access it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is best to use the virtual host to be independent of the machine (ie the URLs of sites are stored in base)
are you under Linux or Win ?

Answer (score 2):

The URL you should type should be:

http://www.YOUROWNDOMAINNAME.COM/magento if you have your own domain name which is hosted by yourhost.

Answer (score 0):

yourhost.com/magento

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server locally, you can go to localhost/magento

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using 
yourhost.com/magento

Also you can use Magento downloader for installation. Go here to [download](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download) it

Answer (score 0):

The URL would be `www.yourdomain.com/magento`

If you want the site to work at `www.yourdomain.com` without the "/magento" you need to move all the files in the magento folder to the public_html folder BEFORE you run the installer.